# Implementing signals on add or modify feature using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qt

I've created a test plug-in in QGIS successfully but have had a hard time implementing a signal on a vector layer event (add or modify feature).  I've added this to my initGUI method:

```
QObject.connect(self.iface.activeLayer(),SIGNAL("featureAdded(QgsFeatureId)"),self.addedGeometry)
```

and this definition:

```
def addedGeometry(self, intValue):
        QMessageBox.information( self.iface.mainWindow(),"Info", "Hi!!!" )
```

I get the following error when I load my plug-in:

```
QObject.connect(self.iface.activeLayer(),SIGNAL("featureAdded(QgsFeatureId)"),self.addedGeometry)
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), QObject, SLOT(), Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
  QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), callable, Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
  QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), SLOT(), Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QObject'
```

I can't find a lot of examples of implementing signals on QGIS objects.

Answer (score 7):

`self.iface.activeLayer()` is relative to what layer is selected in the legend. [If no layer is selected it returns 0](http://doc.qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html) (not a QObject and resolved to 'NoneType'), which can not accept a signal/slot connection.

You'll need to do two things before building the signal/slot connection:

1. Verify that `self.iface.activeLayer()` is in fact returning a `QgsMapLayer` and not 0
2. Verify the active layer's `LayerType` is a [`QgsVectorLayer`](http://doc.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html), which produces the `featureAdded(QgsFeatureId)` signal you're looking to connect to.

There is good information for writing plugins here:

- [PyQGIS Cookbook](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/index.html)
- [QGIS Workshop - (signal/slot section)](http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/event_driven_plugins.html)

Also, consider using [new style PyQt connection syntax](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html) (here, once you have defined a variable 'vlayer' for the vector layer):

```
vlayer.featureAdded.connect(self.addedGeometry)

@pyqtSlot(int)
def addedGeometry(self, intValue):
    # fun stuff here
```