# Cannot Call Function in pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am fairly new to pyQGIS plugin development.
In my "goodNeighbor_dialog_base.ui" file I have two comboBoxes 1 and 2.
When my plugin loads, I am successfully able to load all layers in comboBox1 by calling a custom function. I have another function getcolumns(self) that should populate comboBox2 with attributes of the layer selected in comboBox1, when the user selects a layer in it. To do that I am using the "currentIndexChanged" event as shown in the last line of the code segment

```
 def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.

        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgsInterface
        """
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'goodNeighbor_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)

            if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
                QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

        self.dlg = goodNeighborDialog()
        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&goodNeighbor')

        self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'goodNeighbor')
        self.toolbar.setObjectName(u'goodNeighbor')
        self.dlg.comboBox1.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.getcolumns)
```

then I have written the following function

```
def getcolumns(self):
    print("HI")
    self.dlg.comboBox2.clear()
    layer_name = self.dlg.layerCombo.currentText()
    print("you have selected " + layer_name)
```

The problem is, the function "getcolumns" is not triggering at all.

Comment: Your method seems correct, although I would instead place the signal/slot line `self.dlg.comboBox1.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.getcolumns)` in the `initGui( self )` function. Do you receive any errors in the Python Console when you change selection in your combobox?

Answer (score 2):

to connecting to the SIGNAL emit by the QOobjet as named currentIndexChanged. 
One way is  :

`QObject.connect(self.dlg.comboBox1,SIGNAL("currentIndexChanged(int)"),self.getcolumns)`

But there is also the decorator way as it's recommend in the PyQt doc :
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator

look at this answer to see another example : [example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/31418/53945)

Comment: thanks ..... I was able to solve the problem by removing the dialog creation "self.dlg = goodNeighborDialog()" from add_action() to __init__(self, iface) after comparing with another plugin and it worked. However, I tried your method as well , but I got NameError: global name 'QObject' is not defined.

Comment: QObject is a PyQt object so you should import it before use `PyQt4.QtCore import *`

Answer (score 1):

Any event statement in the `__init__(self, iface)` function only gets called once during initial plugin load.  You need to put the combo event statement at the end of the `initGui()` function so it gets called on any index change like.

```
def initGui(self):
    """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""
    icon_path = ':/plugins/MyPluginName/icon.png'
    self.add_action(
        icon_path,
        text=self.tr(u'Plugin Name'),
        callback=self.run,
        parent=self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.dlg.comboBox1.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.getcolumns)
```